# how to make searchable dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

what I am trying to do is in my below code when I click on the checkbox then I want to make a searchable dropdown list show but right now in my code when I click on the checkbox the searchable dropdown list is not shown.

how can we make a searchable dropdown in my below code?

```js
 
 
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
      aaa.style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("xyz").style.border = "thick solid black";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
     aaa.style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("xyz").style.border = "thick solid white";
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 
  // Initialize select2
  $("#selUser").select2();

  // Read selected option
  $('#but_read').click(function(){
    var username = $('#selUser option:selected').text();
    var userid = $('#selUser').val();

    $('#result').html("id : " + userid + ", name : " + username);

  });
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src= 
"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Select2 CSS --> 
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

<!-- jQuery --> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Select2 JS --> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

 <label for="myCheck">test:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">



<div class="container" id="xyz" style="padding: 20px;">
 
  <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" id="text" style="display:none">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">testing</a>
    </li>
    
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
       <div id="aaa" style="display:none">
        <select id="select_page" style="width:200px;" class="operator"> 
         <option value="">Select name..</option>
         <option value="yellow">ram</option>
        <option value="red">shyam</option>
        <option value="green">mohan</option>
        <option value="green">ramesh</option>
        <option value="green">ramu</option>
  </select>

       </div>
      
    </div>
    
   
  </div>
</div>
```

how can we do that in my below code?

is there any help ??

Comment: I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel... have a look at select2 plugin

Comment: `when i click on checkbox then searchable dropdown list is not shown.` Because you do not HAVE a searchable list? You can try a [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) or select2

Comment: @LelioFaieta select2 plugin i already include this plugin but not work

Comment: <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

<!-- jQuery --> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Select2 JS --> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

Comment: already script use in my code but not work

Comment: You're including jquery **three times** - check out the [select2 stack overflow tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-select2/info), get it working then add bootstrap.

Comment: `$("#selUser").select2();` - your select does not have id=selUser, it has `id=select_page`.  You need to get the basics working first (try a selector for something that actually exists...)